# Can't work out why the square won't animate across the grid

Tags: c#

I cannot for the life of me work out how to get the block that is supposed to be drawn with every loop through the array of "Arxl" objects to animate across the grid.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated, not looking for someone to complete the code for me. just a fresh set of eyes.

```
public partial class Game : Form
{
    //attributes
    private Bitmap _grid;
    private Arxl[,] _cartesianGrid;
    private int _arxlAmount;
    const int ARXL = 4;

    public Game()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _arxlAmount = (gridPictureBox.Height / ARXL);//in case height/arxl is not an even number?

        _cartesianGrid = new Arxl[_arxlAmount, _arxlAmount];
        _grid = new Bitmap(gridPictureBox.Width, gridPictureBox.Height);

        int x;
        int y;

        for (x = 0; x < _arxlAmount; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < _arxlAmount; y++)
            {
                _cartesianGrid[x, y] = new Arxl();
            }
        }

        SetSeed(_cartesianGrid);
    }
    private void SetSeed(Arxl[,] cartesianGrid)
    {
        _cartesianGrid[1, 1].Active = true;
    }

    private void DrawArxl(Bitmap _grid, Arxl[,] cartesianGrid,int arxlAmount)
    {
        int x, y;
        x=0;
        y=0;
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_grid);

        graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        for (x = 1; x < arxlAmount;x++ )
        {
            for (y = 1; y < arxlAmount; y++)
            {
                if (cartesianGrid[x, y].Active==true)
                {
                    cartesianGrid[x, y].Area = new Rectangle(x * ARXL, y * ARXL, ARXL, ARXL);
                    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, cartesianGrid[x, y].Area);
                }
                else if(cartesianGrid[x,y].Active==false)
                {
                    Pen newPen=new Pen(Color.Black);
                    cartesianGrid[x, y].Area = new Rectangle(x * ARXL, y * ARXL, ARXL, ARXL);
                    graphics.DrawRectangle(newPen,cartesianGrid[x, y].Area);
                    newPen.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //GameOfLife(_cartesianGrid, _arxlAmount);
        ScrollBlock(_cartesianGrid, _arxlAmount);
        DrawArxl(_grid, _cartesianGrid, _arxlAmount);
        gridPictureBox.Image = _grid;
    }
    private void ScrollBlock(Arxl[,] cartesianGrid, int arxlAmount)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < arxlAmount; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < arxlAmount; y++)
            {
                if (_cartesianGrid[x, y].Active == true)
                { 
                    if (x>=0)
                    {
                        if (x == (arxlAmount-1))
                        {
                            _cartesianGrid[x, y].Active = false;
                            _cartesianGrid[1, y].Active = true;
                        }
                        else if(x<(arxlAmount-1))
                        {
                            _cartesianGrid[x, y].Active = false;
                            _cartesianGrid[x+1, y].Active = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of voting this question down, it would really be appreciated if you could give me some pointers on using stackoverflow; i'm pretty new to using it and not trying to be lazy or trying to offend anyone.

Comment: Did you try to debug through it? What did you find ouy?

Comment: @user40062 : don't worry about people vote down vote ups, I'd voted it just for the hell of it but it is against the rules just to vote up. Vote down does not mean your question is wrong but only that somebody did not like it ( or did not bother to write the reason ). ALternativley if you are after animation do it in WPF, it is much much easier that Winforms. Also your question might be too general, try to make it more specific.

Comment: @user40062: I didn't vote this up or down, but I can tell you that it's a good candidate for a down-vote. The reason is that this question is just posted code with a "why isn't working" question. Typically, SO questions are for specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spotted your problem.

The problem is that you're updating a cell position (moving it to the right in this particular initial state), but the next iteration in the for loop finds the updated state from the previous iteration, so it updates the cell again, and again,  and when the cycle stops, the cell was scrolled over to its initial cell position!, with no repainting in between.

I'm modifying your code to add an UpdateList that will turn on cells that need to be ON after the grid scan has finished to avoid updating the same "active dot" more than once.  This should show a moving dot from left to right.

```
private void ScrollBlock(Arxl[,] cartesianGrid, int arxlAmount) {
         int x = 0;
         int y = 0;
         List<Point> updateList = new List<Point>();
         for( x = 0; x < arxlAmount; x++ ) {
            for( y = 0; y < arxlAmount; y++ ) {
               if( _cartesianGrid[x, y].Active == true ) {
                  if( x >= 0 ) {
                     if( x == (arxlAmount - 1) ) {
                        _cartesianGrid[x, y].Active = false;
                        //_cartesianGrid[1, y].Active = true;
                        updateList.Add(new Point(1, y));
                     } else if( x < (arxlAmount - 1) ) {
                        _cartesianGrid[x, y].Active = false;
                        //_cartesianGrid[x + 1, y].Active = true;
                        updateList.Add(new Point(x + 1, y));
                     }
                  }
               }

            }
         }
         foreach( var pt in updateList ) {
            _cartesianGrid[pt.X, pt.Y].Active = true;
         }
      }
```

Comment: On an unrelated issue, it is odd that you're passing cartesianGrid as a parameter but instead you're updating the _cartesianGrid field. Either the parameter is unnecesary or you should update it instead of directly updating the field.  Good Luck!

Comment: Just realized that the attributes all belong to the same class. I thought the functions were outside the class. Thanks for pointing out the parameters.

Comment: From my understanding, you have separated the update functionality from the scanning functionality which I had tried to combine. Your solution works perfectly. You have my sincere gratitude, I've learnt from this, which is the ideal outcome.

Answer (score 1):

According to a comment in your code, you want to program the life game. It will not work, if you change the cells in place, because you will have to compute the new state from the unchanged old state. Therefore, you will need to have two game boards, one with the current state and one with the new state. Instead of creating new board all the time, it is better to have two boards and to swap them. In addition, there is no point in storing the `Rectangles` in the board. Therefore, I declare the boards as Boolean matrix.

```
const int CellSize = 4;

private int _boardSize;
private bool[,] _activeBoard, _inactiveBoard;
Bitmap _grid;
```

The form constructor is changed like this

```
public Game()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _boardSize = Math.Min(gridPictureBox.Width, gridPictureBox.Height) / CellSize;
    _grid = new Bitmap(gridPictureBox.Width, gridPictureBox.Height); 
    _activeBoard = new bool[_boardSize, _boardSize];
    _inactiveBoard = new bool[_boardSize, _boardSize];
    SetSeed();
}
```

We initialize the game like this (as an example)

```
private void SetSeed()
{
    _activeBoard[0, 0] = true;
    _activeBoard[7, 4] = true;
    DrawGrid();
}
```

The timer tick does this

```
ScrollBlock();
DrawGrid();
```

The logic in `ScrollBlock` is completely new. We look at the state on the `_activeBoard` and set the state of `_inactiveBoard`. Then we swap the two boards.

```
private void ScrollBlock()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < _boardSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < _boardSize; y++) {
            if (_activeBoard[x, y]) {
                _activeBoard[x, y] = false;
                int newX = x + 1;
                int newY = y;
                if (newX == _boardSize) {
                    newX = 0;
                    newY = (newY + 1) % _boardSize;
                }
                _inactiveBoard[newX, newY] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    SwapBoards();
}
```

The boards are simply swapped like this

```
private void SwapBoards()
{
    bool[,] tmp = _activeBoard;
    _activeBoard = _inactiveBoard;
    _inactiveBoard = tmp;
}
```

And finally `DrawGrid` draws the `_activeBoard`

```
private void DrawGrid()
{
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_grid);
    graphics.Clear(Color.White); 
    for (int x = 0; x < _boardSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < _boardSize; y++) {
            var rect = new Rectangle(x * CellSize, y * CellSize, CellSize, CellSize);
            if (_activeBoard[x, y]) {
                graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, rect);
            } else {
                graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
            }
        }
    }
    gridPictureBox.Image = _grid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'm making a prototype using your code at the moment, rreally useful stuff.

Comment: Finished the protype and it works great. Am now creating another class to contain a 3d array of the cells and a boolean value.

Than you very much for the help.

Comment: The point about the rectangle in the class is especially true.

Answer (score 0):

In your timer try calling gridPictureBox.Invalidate() after you assign the image to the picturebox.  This will force the picturebox to redraw itself.